# wake up gtk window from outside the application

Tags: gtk, signals, vala

I have a application running a gtk window.
When the user exit the app I just want to hide the window but keep the process running.
So when the app is started I want to check

```
if app already running: show window, else create new window...
```

Is there a way to do this without using DBus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to use libunique, for gtk3 apps GtkApplication can be used.

Comment: Besides DBus is the preferred method for desktop IPC, dbus is even approved in fdo.